# How do I center an element within a div with another element nearby?

Tags: html, css

I need to center an element within a div while there is another element nearby.  When I use text-align center, it places the element close but it's not going exactly where I'd like due to another element nearby.  I want the logo element to center exactly while the social element floats to the right.

```css
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
#logo {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
#logo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
#social {
  width: 15%;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}
#social img {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="images/final/logo2.png">
  </div>
  <div id="social">
    <img src="images/final/fb.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w3v7cbdL/

The images are local, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/w3v7cbdL/3/)

To make the logo div centralize irrespective of the div taht holds the social link, you'll have to make the logo div absolute positioned.

Now, to make the absolute positioned logo div centered, you'll have to add `left:0;right:0` to the CSS.

The revised CSS is as follows

**CSS**

```
#logo {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: That fixed it.  Am I just going to have to give the header div a pixel height to counteract the absolute position?

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/w3v7cbdL/4/)..here i have hardcoded the height for header.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this:

```
 #logo {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
```

}

alternatively if #logo would have width: 100px; then position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -50px;

Comment: That worked!  However, now the header div is acting like it's non-existent.  So the rest of the site is pushed up behind the logo.

Comment: you can add body: margin-top: 40px; -the height of your header

Comment: or just to wrap up logo and social with another div. Set this div to position: relative. #logo remain the same

Answer (score 0):

Add center tag and remove float:right from social

```css
    #header {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    #logo {
      width: 30%;
      margin: 10px auto;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
    }
    #logo img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      margin: auto;
    }
    #social {
      width: 15%;
      display: inline;
    }
    #social img {
      width: 25%;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="header">
    <center>     
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="images/final/logo2.png">
      </div>
      <div id="social">
        <img src="images/final/fb.png">
      </div>
    </center>     
    </div>
```